# Is it possible to return a text/plain from Google Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to return just a simple blob of text from Google Cloud Endpoints that would be interpreted by the client as nothing but a text file. Is this possible?

I know it is not possible to return primitives, but can I return an HttpServletResponse and set the content myself or something?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Not tested, just a braindump.

Cloud Endpoints uses ProtoRPC as the underlying transport, which encodes messages as JSON over the wire. You can't change this behavior. The simplest way to return a text file is to just define a simple message class with one String member for the text file:

```
public class TextFile {
  private String text;
  // getText, setText methods ...
}
```

Then your Endpoints method would look something like this:

```
@Api(name = "my_api", ...)
public class MyAPI {
   @ApiMethod(name = "myapi.returntext", httpMethod = "get)
   public TextFile returnText() {
     TextFile response = new TextFile;
     response.setText(read_text_from_some_source());
     return response;
   }
}
```

You'll get a trivial JSON response from this method which should be easy enough to parse the text data out of:

```
{ "text": "<contents_of_text_dump>" }
```

The response may have some extra fields such as 'kind' and 'etag' which you can ignore.

Of course the simplest method if you just want to dump out some text is to forget about Endpoints altogether and just set up a GET handler:

```
public class ReturnText extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
     response.setContentType("text/html");
     response.getWriter().write(read_text_from_some_source());
  }  
}
```

You can then map this to whatever endpoint url you wish in your web.xml.